# Problem with background pictures (\AddToShipoutPicture)

Tags: graphics, backgrounds, eso-pic

EDIT: adding \usepackage{grffile} did the trick!!!

I'm having some troubles with the frontpage of my document.
I use `\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}` to print 2 `.eps` files as background on which I print the text:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} % Default font size is 12pt, it can be changed here
\usepackage{geometry} % Required to change the page size to A4
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{epstopdf}   % allow for the usage of eps files
\geometry{a4paper, twoside} % Set the page size to be A4 as opposed to the default US Letter
\graphicspath{{./Images/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(10,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{E:/Cloud storage/Dropbox/LaTeX/JavaScript/data/images/overview.eps}
\vfill}}}

\newcommand\BackgroundPico{%
\put(0,350){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{E:/Cloud storage/Dropbox/LaTeX/JavaScript/data/images/banner.png}
\vfill}}}

\begin{document}
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPico}
    \cleardoublepage
    \begin{titlepage}
        Some text
    \end{titlepage}   
\end{document}
```

The result is that the background picture is inserted AND it is referenced as text twice more:

[image]

in this picture you see the path to the `overview.eps` printed twice before the actual picture. If you look closely above the green bar (used to be more elaborate that is why it is an `.eps`) you see the same there, just outside the page, for the other picture.

My guess is that this is due to the multiple compile runs that are needed for updating links, index etc.... But I'm not sure and have no idea where to look anymore.

I tried to take as much out as possible to keep it readable. I hope someone can shed some light on this!?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please complete your example with `\documentclass` and the minimum set of `\usepackage`s to make it compilable.

Comment: I tried to remove everything that isn't nessecary, hope I didn't miss anything. Anyway, I edited the original post with the minimal needed tex code. Only things missing are the actual image files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w64kawbmm1lga1h/banner.png?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/vgla4pbt9y6ntqp/overview.eps?dl=0

Comment: You're including an EPS and a PNG. That means you're compiling with pdflatex and the EPS is converted on-the-fly. However, you have spaces in your paths, which may require the [`grffile` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/grffile)...

Comment: Thanks!!!! that did the trick. I could have looked for ages and not figured this out!