# Problem with Background Picture

Tags: backgrounds, wallpaper

Edited for an MWE (that hopefully works)
I'm having trouble with the coding.
I have this one picture, and I edited another picture to base it off that.

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

As you could probably tell, that shaded area of is very important in my project.
I am trying to get a line of text to go there. Below is my code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} 
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics[scale=1.25]{pic1}}} 
\centering;
\vspace*{5cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
\textbf{Main Title Text Over Here on top}\\
{\LARGE Smaller Text Down Here}\par 
\vspace*{1cm}
{\Huge My Name}\par 
\endgroup

\newpage
\end{document}
```

Now, it works nice and fine for the first picture, but for the second picture with the same code:

[image: picture 3]

[image: picture 4]

I don't quite understand..
Both pictures have the same resolution, but why does it treat the other picture differently?

Comment: It would help to know the document class and what package \AddToShipoutPicture comes from.  For example, if using standalone one would expect the two pages to have different sizes.  If you are using a KOMA class, we are talking an entirely different set of problems.

Comment: Oops. My bad @JohnKormylo

\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} 

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry} 

\input{structure}

Those are all in the header. (I didn't include the font packages and some other irrelevant things like that). Hopefully that clears things up.

Comment: There are a number of questions here from people having problems with \AddTo ShipoutPicture,  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225020/problem-with-background-pictures-addtoshipoutpicture?s=2|1.4335 at least has a MWE.

Comment: I tried adding the \usepackage{grffile} to the header, but that didn't work. I'll get right on it for the MWE, sorry about that

Comment: Edited and added the MWE

Comment: when I try with `\includegraphics[scale=.55]{bigim}` , just fine???

Comment: images dimensions are differents for pdftex `<image2= 1279.78125pt x 1656.1875pt>
<image1= 618.41779pt x 800.30537pt>` so you need to use different scale or resize one of them.

Comment: 0.55 as the scalar is pretty darn close to the original picture, but there's about a chunk of 1275 by 200 pixels missing. But thank you for pointing out the difference in the image dimensions in pdftex. I'll try and resize them to become similar, and but if needed I can resort to using the 0.55 as the scale. Thank you so much!

Comment: @touhami It seems your comment is the answer. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer (maybe with a bit of explanation where to pay attention with the resolutions/dimensions)?

Comment: Yes, touhami's comment was a good answer.

Also, it's worth noting that all of this could have been solved with a simple [width=216 mm, height=279mm] (dimensions of a paper). Sigh. I feel like we sometimes overthink things way too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the image dimensions are already too large. One should look for a better scale.

```
\includegraphics[scale=.48]{pic1}
```

or

```
\includegraphics[scale=.55]{pic1}
```

One can also try with

```
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{pic1}
```

this will scale the image such that it fit the width of paper
or

```
\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{pic1}
```

this will scale the image such that it fit the height of paper
or

```
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{pic1}
```

this will scale the image such that it fit the paper.